# How do I avoid repetitive if statements without interrupting event to run other actions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

There are two classes that interact in this problem. I'd like to note I'm using Unity:

1. TaskHandler

```
public class TaskHandler{

    public event Action<GameObject> TaskResponses;

    private void Update(){
        if (someCondition){
            TaskResponses?.Invoke(taskObj);
        }
    }
}
```

2. TaskBase

```
public class TaskBase: MonoBehaviour{

    private TaskHandler taskHandler;

    private void Start(){
        taskHandler = gameObject.GetComponent<TaskHandler>();
        taskHandler.TaskResponses += TaskResponse;
    }

    private void TaskResponse(GameObject taskObj){
        //if check so that only specific TaskResponses run.
        if (taskObj == gameObject){
                //functions
            }
    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is with methods that extend `TaskResponse()`.

```cs
public class SpecificTask{

    public override void TaskResponse(GameObject taskObj)
    {
        base.TaskResponse(taskObj);

        //another if check
        if (taskObj == thisTaskObj){
            //some other functionality
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to do another `if` check. I tried the following:

```
public class TaskBase: MonoBehaviour{
    //Start() method omitted

    private void TaskResponse(GameObject taskObj){
        //if check so that only specific TaskResponses run.
        if (taskObj == gameObject){
                //functions
            }
        else{
            //Effectively stops code from SpecificTask to continue running,
            //But other Actions are no longer called.
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

But the `return` statement stops `TaskReponses()` from other classes to run. By that, I mean that if I had Class `Task1` and `Task2`, and `Task1`'s `TaskResponse()` runs first, but it runs the else statement, it stops and does not run `Task2`'s `TaskResponse()`.

How can I improve my code to stop writing repetitive `if` checks, while have my code check all `Action` like I want it to? Should I not be using `event` for this scenario at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it not `void` but rather `bool` which indicates if the method was successfully terminated or aborted like e.g.

```
public class TaskBase
{
    public virtual bool TaskResponse(GameObject taskObj)
    {
        if(taskObj != thisObj) return false;

        // Default stuff to happen

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
public class MyTask
{
    public override bool TaskResponse (GameObject taskObj)
    {
        if(!base.TaskResponse(taskObj)) return false;

        // Default stuff already happened
        // Now you can add additional stuff here

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively if you want to avoid that `if` check entirely what I also do often is using separate methods like

```
public class TaskBase
{
    public void TaskResponse (GameObject taskObj)
    {
        if(taskObj != thisObj) return;

        TaskResponseInternal();
    }

    protected virtual void TaskResponseInternal() 
    {
        // Default stuff to happen
    }
}
```

And then simply override that instead

```
public class MyTask
{
    protected override void TaskResponseInternal ()
    {
        // If you want also the default stuff
        base.TaskResponseInternal();

        // Additional stuff to happen
    }
}
```

Comment: I poorly worded my question and explained it. I updated the question to provide more detail. The problem I have is that I tried the `return;` statement, but it stops other `TaskResponse()` in the event from running.